# Detailed trigger.io setup guide?

Tags: trigger.io

Short version:  Can anyone point me to a more detailed setup guide for trigger.io installation on a fresh windows 8 system (beyond the getting started tutorial at https://trigger.io/docs/current/getting_started/getting_started.html)?

Long version:

First some background:  I'm not a professional developer, but I'm also not a complete novice when it comes to programming stuff.  While I prefer GUI interfaces, I'm comfortable with a command line and poking around behind the scenes of things.  I previously did a basic 'for fun' Android app using Eclips and the Android SDK.  I've also taken a look at PhoneGapBuild and JQueryMobile and was able to make and test a simple app with that.  I'm looking to make my first real app, which will be pretty basic - essentially a glorified 'user manual' app that provides various content I have the copyright to for a fee via in-app purchasing.  Trigger.io seems to be the best solution for cross-platform quick development that allows access to the various in-app purchasing APIs.

My system:  A Microsoft Surface Pro tablet running Windows 8

My issue:  I've been unable to get the basic hello world app to actually run via either the web (firefox) option or the android options (emulator and debug connection to my android phone).  Building works fine, but that took a little effort to get functional too.  While the getting started guides were a little helpful, there are a lot of things they mention in passing or essentially skim over.  For example, having Java and Python installed is a prereq, but buried in the text of one of the pages.  Ditto for node.js and the actual Android SDK.  Likewise, when i first tried to run the demo app, it automatically downloaded and installed the Android SDK, however it appeared to be an incomplete install when I ran the SDK Manager app.  Right now, I get the following errors when I try to run an app (both from the web gui and from the command line):

- Emulator:  right after choosing "attempt to automatically launch the emulator", windows pops up with 'emulator-arm.exe has stopped working'.
- Web:  right after 'Forge tools running at version 3.3.54', I get an
  error 'environment can only contain strings'
- Device:  right after 'Creating APK with aapt', I get an error '[Error
  2] The system cannot find the file specified'.  (Examining the
  forge-error.log, there are a whole bunch of traceback calls to
  various python scripts).

Note my brother, who has a Mac had little trouble installing xcode and the trigger.io toolkit and getting an IOS hello world app to run.  Thus, while I'd be happy to trudge through my individual issues, I'd suggest that other users might find value in a lower level 'system setup guide', that assumes you have a stock install of Windows and steps you through everything you need to do, such as install X, add Y to the path, run Z.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Going through the three issues you lay out:

1. This sounds like a problem with the Android SDK: I'd recommend opening the AVD manager and recreating your AVD, or completely removing the SDK and starting over.
2. We had a similar report 6 months ago, but it just went away for that user after re-running so we weren't able to get to the bottom of it. I'd recommend upgrading to the latest Node and npm, and if you're still having trouble, send us the log output.
3. This was a limitation of our platform versions < v1.4.48 - key utilities were moved in Android SDK 22. Use v1.4 as your platform version (or v1.4.48 or later) and this will be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  Unfortunately I still haven't been able to get it to work on Windows 8.  However I don't think it's necessarily a trigger.io issue, as I can't even launch the emulator directly from within the Android SDK.  Google searches turn up lots of people having general issues with Windows 8 and the Android SDK.  Luckily I have a Windows 7 machines available and was able to get things working on that, although it did require some tinkering.  I'll post more below for reference for others looking for help.

Answer (score 0):

As I indicated above, I wasn't able to get things working on Windows 8, but I was with Windows 7.  Here is a step by step guide for other's that might need help setting things up from a baseline install of Windows 7 to get Android apps working.  In my case it was Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit.

Note however that I found many of my issues were due to installing a mix of 64 bit and 32 bit versions of the various software.  I recommend ONLY installing 32 bit versions of the below.

1. Download the Java SE Development Kit (JDK) from www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html.  Note that the Java Runtime Environment (JRE) is NOT sufficient.  In my case I installed the Windows x86 v7u21 file.  During installation, select all the default options and make sure to select the option to add Java to the system PATH (wasn't selected by default for me).
2. Download Python from python.org/download/  Again, I picked the x86 version 3.3.2, which was the latest.  And during install be sure install for all users and to check the option to add Python to the system PATH.
3. Download the Android SDK ADT bundle from developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download  Select the 32 bit version.  The file is just a zip file, so once I downloaded it I unzipped it into a new directory in my root C: directory (e.g. C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130522).
4. Run the SDK Manager program in this new top level directory.  Click on the update button to update anything that might need to be updated.
5. Follow the getting starting instructions here developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html to create a blank app and an AVD for the android emulator and to launch it from within the Android ADT environment in order to ensure everything is working.  It didn't work for my at first because I selected a Nexus device to emulate which required too much memory.  I recommend picking a more basic device like the HVGA one.  Note that the emulator can take 5-10 minutes to fully boot up.  As long as the Andoird logo is still flashing it's working.  You can leave the emulator running but close down the rest of the SDK windows at this point.
6. Download and install the Tigger.io toolkit.  (You need to create a few account first to get the download link).  Once it installs, run the toolkit and create a default app per the instructions here:  trigger.io/docs/current/getting_started/mobile.html
7. Note that I got the aapt error when trying to run the default app, and changing the app version to v1.4.48 didn't resolve it.  In order to fix it I had to edit one of the Python scripts per the instructions here: stackoverflow.com/questions/17044682/couldnt-find-aapt-tool-you-may-need-to-update-your-android-sdk-including-pl
8. Be sure to use the app settings page to point to the directory you installed the Android SDK in.
9. Once you do all this, you should be able to click on the Android button and trigger.io should do it's thing and build / package the app into the emulator window you still have running.